# How to return a Boolean variable with two different parameter's?

Tags: java, methods, boolean

//When method Parity is called, boolean variable Parity does not change to incorporate method. I dont know what is being returned by the method, I assume its Val1 and Val2 but idk.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.Random;
  public class DiceRoll
  {
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
       Random rand = new Random ();
       
       int gameNumber = 0;
       int compPoint = 0;
       int playerPoint = 0;
       int currentGame = 0;
       int compRoll = 0;
       int playerRoll = 0;
       int compRoll2 = 0;
       int playerRoll2 = 0;
       int sumComp = 0;
       int sumPlayer = 0;
       int Val1 = 0;
       int Val2 =0;
       boolean Parity = false;
       
       System.out.println (" How many games? ");
       gameNumber = scan.nextInt ();
       System.out.println ("Number of games: "+gameNumber);
       
       System.out.println ("Computer Wins: "+compPoint);
       System.out.println ("Player Wins: "+playerPoint);
       System.out.println ("");
       
       currentGame = currentGame+1;
       System.out.println ("Current Game:" +currentGame);
       
       compRoll = DiceRoll(10);
       playerRoll = DiceRoll(10);
       compRoll2 = DiceRoll (10);
       playerRoll2 = DiceRoll (10);
       sumComp = (compRoll + compRoll2);
       sumPlayer = (playerRoll + playerRoll2);
       
       
       System.out.printf ("Computer: %d %d Total: %d \nPlayer: %d %d Total: %d" , compRoll, compRoll2,                         sumComp, playerRoll, playerRoll2, sumPlayer);
       System.out.println ("");
       
       //parityCheck = Val1;
       if (Parity(Val1, Val2) == true)
       {
            System.out.println ("Parity: True");
       }
       else
       {
            System.out.println ("Parity: False");
       }
       
                
       
  }
  public static int DiceRoll (int sides)
  {
      int rollTotal = 0 ;
      int minRand = 1;
      int maxRand = sides;
      int range = (maxRand - minRand)+ 1;
       
       rollTotal = (int)(Math.random()* range) +minRand;
       
       return rollTotal;
       
  }
  public static boolean Parity (int Val1, int Val2)
  {
       int evenSum = 0;
       int oddSum = 0;
       int sumComp2 = 0;
       int sumPlayer2 = 0;
       
       sumComp2= Val1;
       sumPlayer2= Val2;
       
      if (sumComp2 %2 == 0 && sumPlayer2 == 0 || sumComp2 %2 == 1 && sumPlayer2 == 1)
       {
            return true;
       }
       else
       {
            return false;
       } 
       
       //return ();
  }
```

}

I have tried changing the println statements to display Val1 and Val2 but as the paramtres must call ints, they are unable to display anything but numbers.

Comment: debug your code, or at the very least put print statements in there.

Comment: You have a variable `Parity` in the main method and a method `Parity()`. The variable `Parity` only changes when you assign something to it. It doesn't change when you call the similarly called method `Parity()`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"When method Parity is called, boolean variable Parity does not change to incorporate method. ..."*

In Java, there is no link between names.  Syntax, and ultimately the context of the statement, is used to disseminate the object.
Thus, a class, method, and variable, all named *Parity* would be different objects.

You'll have to assign the *Parity* variable the returned value of the *Parity* method.